# Sort Beautiful soup elements by text value

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've search about this on the internet on how I could do this but it seems to have a different type of question & goal.

So I have this soup right here. You can have a test on this code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="300">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=1','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 1</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=7','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 7</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=2','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 2</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=8','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 8</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=3','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 3</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=9','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 9</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=4','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 4</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=10','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 10</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=5','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 5</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=11','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 11</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=6','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 6</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=12','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 12</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")#use any parser you want.

for td in soup.find_all("td"):
    print(td)# This outputs the not sorted <td> tags
```

Not sorted `<td>` tags.

```
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=1','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 1</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=7','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 7</a></td>
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=2','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 2</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=8','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 8</a></td>
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=3','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 3</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=9','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 9</a></td>
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=4','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 4</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=10','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 10</a></td>
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=5','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 5</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=11','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 11</a></td>
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=6','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 6</a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=12','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 12</a></td>
```

Now you can see on the `.text` of every `<td>` tag there is a text for example "lesson 1" , "lesson 7", "lesson 2" and so on... Now what I wanted to have is sort this `<td>` tags by its text value also by the number. So I'd want to have an output like this.

```
<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=1','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 1</a></td> 

<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=2','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 2</a></td> 

<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=3','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 3</a></td> 

<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=4','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 4</a></td> 

<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=5','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 5</a></td> 

<td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=6','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 6</a></td> 

<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=7','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 7</a></td> 

<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=8','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 8</a></td> 

<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=9','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 9</a></td> 

<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=10','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 10</a></td> 

<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=11','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 11</a></td> 

<td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=12','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 12</a></td>
```

Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job and give you a list of the sorted `td` tags that contain an `a` tag.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="300">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=1','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 1</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=7','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 7</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=2','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 2</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=8','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 8</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=3','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 3</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=9','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 9</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=4','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 4</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=10','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 10</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=5','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 5</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=11','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 11</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%"><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=6','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 6</a></td>
          <td><a href="javascript:newDoWindowOpen('http://ohelo.org/japn/lang/genki_vocab_table.php?lesson=12','Vocab','500','500',0)">lesson 12</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


# Function takes one <td> tag, finds it's child which is an <a> tag
# it then finds the text inside it and then splits it to get the number
# this is then returned to the sorted function as an int
def sort_soup(item):
    item = list(item.children)[0].text
    data = item.split(" ")
    return int(data[1])


out = soup.findAll('td') 
out = sorted(out, key= lambda elem: sort_soup(elem))
print(out)
```

Comment: Hello @Aasim , this is great! Thanks a lot! I think I should be using `soup.find_all` anyways they're just the same I think it's just on the version. Thanks a lot!